# How to append developer logs in a Dart CLI application

Tags: dart, logging

Dart natively supports a [developer log function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-developer/log.html), which in Flutter automatically appends logging output to the device log.

But when I build a (server) CLI application in Dart, these logs appear to be only accessible via DevTools.

Where can I find the API to build a custom appender?
(Or is there already a Pub package that can append to console and/or rotating log files?)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400502/85472
Basically you need to register a Logger yourself in order to get output when using the log function from the `dart:developer` package. You can also see how I do it in the [source code of the small package](https://github.com/maks/bonsai_dart/blob/main/lib/src/bonsai_base.dart#L19) I've published.